# nginx on El Capitan Mac unhelpful empty server reply

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, osx-elcapitan

My company moved me from Linux to Mac; a shout out to Linux for making nginx config easier than Mac; or maybe, and most likely I don't know what I've done wrong.

On my new Mac Book Pro, I install homebrew, php70, php-fpm, mysql, and nginx. PHP 7 and PHP-FPM are running using:

```
$ php -v
$ PHP 7.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2016 14:50:47) ( NTS )
  Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.0.9, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
  with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

Homebrew is installed and nginx is started using:

```
$ sudo brew services start nginx
$ Successfully started `nginx` (label: homebrew.mxcl.nginx);
```

To keep it simple I have a very simple nxinx.conf:

```
user  <user> staff;

worker_processes auto;

events {  
  worker_connections  1024;
}

error_log  /Users/<user>/dev/html/nginx-logs/dev.static.error.log;

http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  gzip  on;

  server {
    listen 80;

    server_name dev;

    root /Users/<user>/dev/html;

    index index.php index.html;

    # This bit tells nginx how to serve files that are in /css and /img
    location ~ ^/(css|img) {
      gzip_static on;

      # Don't cache anything
      expires -1;
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

      break;
    }

    # For everything that isn't in /css or /img
    location / {

        # otherwise go to index.php.
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php\$is_args\$args;

        # Don't cache anything
        expires -1;
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:7777;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/http$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
  }
}
```

The fast CGI pass is set to 127.0.0.1:7777 and the listen in php-fpm is also set to 127.0.0.1:7777. Not much is set in the php-fpm:

The php-fpm www.conf has this:

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can we used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('www' here)
[www]

; Per pool prefix
; It only applies on the following directives:
; - 'access.log'
; - 'slowlog'
; - 'listen' (unixsocket)
; - 'chroot'
; - 'chdir'
; - 'php_values'
; - 'php_admin_values'
; When not set, the global prefix (or /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.9) applies instead.
; Note: This directive can also be relative to the global prefix.
; Default Value: none
;prefix = /path/to/pools/$pool

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = <user>
group = staff

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:7777

; Set listen(2) backlog.
; Default Value: 511 (-1 on FreeBSD and OpenBSD)
;listen.backlog = 511

; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions.
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
;listen.owner = _www
;listen.group = _www
;listen.mode = 0660
; When POSIX Access Control Lists are supported you can set them using
; these options, value is a comma separated list of user/group names.
; When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored
;listen.acl_users =
;listen.acl_groups =

; List of addresses (IPv4/IPv6) of FastCGI clients which are allowed to connect.
; Equivalent to the FCGI_WEB_SERVER_ADDRS environment variable in the original
; PHP FCGI (5.2.2+). Makes sense only with a tcp listening socket. Each address
; must be separated by a comma. If this value is left blank, connections will be
; accepted from any ip address.
; Default Value: any
;listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the pool processes (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lower priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool processes will inherit the master process priority
;         unless it specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
; process.priority = -19

; Choose how the process manager will control the number of child processes.
; Possible Values:
;   static  - a fixed number (pm.max_children) of child processes;
;   dynamic - the number of child processes are set dynamically based on the
;             following directives. With this process management, there will be
;             always at least 1 children.
;             pm.max_children      - the maximum number of children that can
;                                    be alive at the same time.
;             pm.start_servers     - the number of children created on startup.
;             pm.min_spare_servers - the minimum number of children in 'idle'
;                                    state (waiting to process). If the number
;                                    of 'idle' processes is less than this
;                                    number then some children will be created.
;             pm.max_spare_servers - the maximum number of children in 'idle'
;                                    state (waiting to process). If the number
;                                    of 'idle' processes is greater than this
;                                    number then some children will be killed.
;  ondemand - no children are created at startup. Children will be forked when
;             new requests will connect. The following parameter are used:
;             pm.max_children           - the maximum number of children that
;                                         can be alive at the same time.
;             pm.process_idle_timeout   - The number of seconds after which
;                                         an idle process will be killed.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm = dynamic

; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
; maximum number of child processes when pm is set to 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'.
; This value sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be
; served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork.
; Equivalent to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP
; CGI. The below defaults are based on a server without much resources. Don't
; forget to tweak pm.* to fit your needs.
; Note: Used when pm is set to 'static', 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm.max_children = 5

; The number of child processes created on startup.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Default Value: min_spare_servers + (max_spare_servers - min_spare_servers) / 2
pm.start_servers = 2

; The desired minimum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.min_spare_servers = 1

; The desired maximum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
;pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;

; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
;pm.max_requests = 500

; The URI to view the FPM status page. If this value is not set, no URI will be
; recognized as a status page. It shows the following informations:
;   pool                 - the name of the pool;
;   process manager      - static, dynamic or ondemand;
;   start time           - the date and time FPM has started;
;   start since          - number of seconds since FPM has started;
;   accepted conn        - the number of request accepted by the pool;
;   listen queue         - the number of request in the queue of pending
;                          connections (see backlog in listen(2));
;   max listen queue     - the maximum number of requests in the queue
;                          of pending connections since FPM has started;
;   listen queue len     - the size of the socket queue of pending connections;
;   idle processes       - the number of idle processes;
;   active processes     - the number of active processes;
;   total processes      - the number of idle + active processes;
;   max active processes - the maximum number of active processes since FPM
;                          has started;
;   max children reached - number of times, the process limit has been reached,
;                          when pm tries to start more children (works only for
;                          pm 'dynamic' and 'ondemand');
; Value are updated in real time.
; Example output:
;   pool:                 www
;   process manager:      static
;   start time:           01/Jul/2011:17:53:49 +0200
;   start since:          62636
;   accepted conn:        190460
;   listen queue:         0
;   max listen queue:     1
;   listen queue len:     42
;   idle processes:       4
;   active processes:     11
;   total processes:      15
;   max active processes: 12
;   max children reached: 0
;
; By default the status page output is formatted as text/plain. Passing either
; 'html', 'xml' or 'json' in the query string will return the corresponding
; output syntax. Example:
;   http://www.foo.bar/status
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?json
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?html
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?xml
;
; By default the status page only outputs short status. Passing 'full' in the
; query string will also return status for each pool process.
; Example:
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?full
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?json&full
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?html&full
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?xml&full
; The Full status returns for each process:
;   pid                  - the PID of the process;
;   state                - the state of the process (Idle, Running, ...);
;   start time           - the date and time the process has started;
;   start since          - the number of seconds since the process has started;
;   requests             - the number of requests the process has served;
;   request duration     - the duration in µs of the requests;
;   request method       - the request method (GET, POST, ...);
;   request URI          - the request URI with the query string;
;   content length       - the content length of the request (only with POST);
;   user                 - the user (PHP_AUTH_USER) (or '-' if not set);
;   script               - the main script called (or '-' if not set);
;   last request cpu     - the %cpu the last request consumed
;                          it's always 0 if the process is not in Idle state
;                          because CPU calculation is done when the request
;                          processing has terminated;
;   last request memory  - the max amount of memory the last request consumed
;                          it's always 0 if the process is not in Idle state
;                          because memory calculation is done when the request
;                          processing has terminated;
; If the process is in Idle state, then informations are related to the
; last request the process has served. Otherwise informations are related to
; the current request being served.
; Example output:
;   ************************
;   pid:                  31330
;   state:                Running
;   start time:           01/Jul/2011:17:53:49 +0200
;   start since:          63087
;   requests:             12808
;   request duration:     1250261
;   request method:       GET
;   request URI:          /test_mem.php?N=10000
;   content length:       0
;   user:                 -
;   script:               /home/fat/web/docs/php/test_mem.php
;   last request cpu:     0.00
;   last request memory:  0
;
; Note: There is a real-time FPM status monitoring sample web page available
;       It's available in: /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.9/share/php/fpm/status.html
;
; Note: The value must start with a leading slash (/). The value can be
;       anything, but it may not be a good idea to use the .php extension or it
;       may conflict with a real PHP file.
; Default Value: not set
;pm.status_path = /status

; The ping URI to call the monitoring page of FPM. If this value is not set, no
; URI will be recognized as a ping page. This could be used to test from outside
; that FPM is alive and responding, or to
; - create a graph of FPM availability (rrd or such);
; - remove a server from a group if it is not responding (load balancing);
; - trigger alerts for the operating team (24/7).
; Note: The value must start with a leading slash (/). The value can be
;       anything, but it may not be a good idea to use the .php extension or it
;       may conflict with a real PHP file.
; Default Value: not set
;ping.path = /ping

; This directive may be used to customize the response of a ping request. The
; response is formatted as text/plain with a 200 response code.
; Default Value: pong
;ping.response = pong

; The access log file
; Default: not set
;access.log = log/$pool.access.log

; The access log format.
; The following syntax is allowed
;  %%: the '%' character
;  %C: %CPU used by the request
;      it can accept the following format:
;      - %{user}C for user CPU only
;      - %{system}C for system CPU only
;      - %{total}C  for user + system CPU (default)
;  %d: time taken to serve the request
;      it can accept the following format:
;      - %{seconds}d (default)
;      - %{miliseconds}d
;      - %{mili}d
;      - %{microseconds}d
;      - %{micro}d
;  %e: an environment variable (same as $_ENV or $_SERVER)
;      it must be associated with embraces to specify the name of the env
;      variable. Some exemples:
;      - server specifics like: %{REQUEST_METHOD}e or %{SERVER_PROTOCOL}e
;      - HTTP headers like: %{HTTP_HOST}e or %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}e
;  %f: script filename
;  %l: content-length of the request (for POST request only)
;  %m: request method
;  %M: peak of memory allocated by PHP
;      it can accept the following format:
;      - %{bytes}M (default)
;      - %{kilobytes}M
;      - %{kilo}M
;      - %{megabytes}M
;      - %{mega}M
;  %n: pool name
;  %o: output header
;      it must be associated with embraces to specify the name of the header:
;      - %{Content-Type}o
;      - %{X-Powered-By}o
;      - %{Transfert-Encoding}o
;      - ....
;  %p: PID of the child that serviced the request
;  %P: PID of the parent of the child that serviced the request
;  %q: the query string
;  %Q: the '?' character if query string exists
;  %r: the request URI (without the query string, see %q and %Q)
;  %R: remote IP address
;  %s: status (response code)
;  %t: server time the request was received
;      it can accept a strftime(3) format:
;      %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z (default)
;      The strftime(3) format must be encapsuled in a %{<strftime_format>}t tag
;      e.g. for a ISO8601 formatted timestring, use: %{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t
;  %T: time the log has been written (the request has finished)
;      it can accept a strftime(3) format:
;      %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z (default)
;      The strftime(3) format must be encapsuled in a %{<strftime_format>}t tag
;      e.g. for a ISO8601 formatted timestring, use: %{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t
;  %u: remote user
;
; Default: "%R - %u %t \"%m %r\" %s"
;access.format = "%R - %u %t \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %f %{mili}d %{kilo}M %C%%"

; The log file for slow requests
; Default Value: not set
; Note: slowlog is mandatory if request_slowlog_timeout is set
;slowlog = log/$pool.log.slow

; The timeout for serving a single request after which a PHP backtrace will be
; dumped to the 'slowlog' file. A value of '0s' means 'off'.
; Available units: s(econds)(default), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Value: 0
;request_slowlog_timeout = 0

; The timeout for serving a single request after which the worker process will
; be killed. This option should be used when the 'max_execution_time' ini option
; does not stop script execution for some reason. A value of '0' means 'off'.
; Available units: s(econds)(default), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Value: 0
;request_terminate_timeout = 0

; Set open file descriptor rlimit.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Chroot to this directory at the start. This value must be defined as an
; absolute path. When this value is not set, chroot is not used.
; Note: you can prefix with '$prefix' to chroot to the pool prefix or one
; of its subdirectories. If the pool prefix is not set, the global prefix
; will be used instead.
; Note: chrooting is a great security feature and should be used whenever
;       possible. However, all PHP paths will be relative to the chroot
;       (error_log, sessions.save_path, ...).
; Default Value: not set
;chroot =

; Chdir to this directory at the start.
; Note: relative path can be used.
; Default Value: current directory or / when chroot
;chdir = /var/www

; Redirect worker stdout and stderr into main error log. If not set, stdout and
; stderr will be redirected to /dev/null according to FastCGI specs.
; Note: on highloaded environement, this can cause some delay in the page
; process time (several ms).
; Default Value: no
;catch_workers_output = yes

; Clear environment in FPM workers
; Prevents arbitrary environment variables from reaching FPM worker processes
; by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this
; pool configuration are added.
; Setting to "no" will make all environment variables available to PHP code
; via getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER.
; Default Value: yes
;clear_env = no

; Limits the extensions of the main script FPM will allow to parse. This can
; prevent configuration mistakes on the web server side. You should only limit
; FPM to .php extensions to prevent malicious users to use other extensions to
; exectute php code.
; Note: set an empty value to allow all extensions.
; Default Value: .php
;security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7

; Pass environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH. All $VARIABLEs are taken from
; the current environment.
; Default Value: clean env
;env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
;env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
;env[TMP] = /tmp
;env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
;env[TEMP] = /tmp

; Additional php.ini defines, specific to this pool of workers. These settings
; overwrite the values previously defined in the php.ini. The directives are the
; same as the PHP SAPI:
;   php_value/php_flag             - you can set classic ini defines which can
;                                    be overwritten from PHP call 'ini_set'.
;   php_admin_value/php_admin_flag - these directives won't be overwritten by
;                                     PHP call 'ini_set'
; For php_*flag, valid values are on, off, 1, 0, true, false, yes or no.

; Defining 'extension' will load the corresponding shared extension from
; extension_dir. Defining 'disable_functions' or 'disable_classes' will not
; overwrite previously defined php.ini values, but will append the new value
; instead.

; Note: path INI options can be relative and will be expanded with the prefix
; (pool, global or /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.9)

; Default Value: nothing is defined by default except the values in php.ini and
;                specified at startup with the -d argument
;php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f www@my.domain.com
;php_flag[display_errors] = off
;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
;php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M
```

My hosts file is:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       dev
```

My dev path to html and php files is:

```
/Users/<user>/dev/html/index.html
/Users/<user>/dev/html/index.php
/Users/<user>/dev/html/nginx-logs/dev.static.error.log
```

Before I setup the fastcgi the static index.html served by going to http://dev. Now I get a:

```
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE using curl or a web page
```

The nginx error logs have:

```
2016/08/15 08:04:25 [error] 1034#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php\\", client: 127.0.0.1, server: dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "dev"
2016/08/15 08:04:25 [error] 1034#0: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php\\", client: 127.0.0.1, server: dev, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "dev", referrer: "http://dev/"
2016/08/15 08:04:27 [error] 1034#0: *3 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php\\", client: 127.0.0.1, server: dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "dev"
2016/08/15 08:04:27 [error] 1034#0: *4 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php\\", client: 127.0.0.1, server: dev, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "dev", referrer: "http://dev/"
```

I've been scouring google and tried all the homebrew setups that end with this similar result.

I'm running nginx as sudo so I can use port 80. No errors are shown when running:
    sudo nginx

Every time I've made a change to php-fpm, I've restarted it. Same for nginx, reload the config and then restart ( to ensure the config is applied ).

I also have been trying to figure out how to set fastcgi_pass as a unix sock; when I had my linux local dev setup I used a unix sock and it worked very reliably.

I currently out of ideas. Any help is appreciated.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

I think this line in your `nginx.conf` is wrong:

```
try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php\$is_args\$args;
```

if there are no arguments, it will try to open `/index.php\\`. This should be better:

```
try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

Comment: Thx I now get File not found.when using http://dev or http://dev/html/index.php ( explicitly trying file path ).

Comment: nginx error log has 2016/08/15 09:48:52 [error] 1943#0: *6 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:7777", host: "dev"

Comment: `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/http$fastcgi_script_name;` also looks strange, can you try `fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

Comment: using sudo nginx -s stop: [emerg] unknown "fastc" variable with the example in the last line of your comment.

Comment: please double check for typos (perhaps in some other line?)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I believe that the SCRIPT filepath was causing the issue. I read https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/ and adjusted my nginx.conf appropriately. Here is what renders php when browsing http://dev:

```
user  <user> staff;

worker_processes auto;

events {  
   worker_connections  1024;
}

error_log  /Users/<user>/dev/html/nginx-logs/dev.static.error.log;

http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  gzip  on;

  server {
    listen 80;

    server_name dev;

    root /Users/<user>/dev/html;

    index index.php index.html;

    # This bit tells nginx how to serve files that are in /css and /img
      need this
    location ~ ^/(css|img) {
      gzip_static on;

      # Don't cache anything
      expires -1;
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

      break;
    }

    # For everything that isn't in /css or /img
    location / {

        # This tells NGINX to first find and serve a file specified by the uri,
        # otherwise go to index.php.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        # Don't cache anything
        expires -1;
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:7777;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help